# Create month and year column to speed up timestamp query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a big log table in mariadb/mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `user` CHAR(4) NOT, NULL,
    `dateCreated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `dateUpdated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I am trying to query logs based on user and date created by month and year:

```
select * from logs where month(dateCreated) = '9' and year(dateCreated) = '2016' and user = '1234'
```

**Question:**
Should I created two columns called month and year, and index the month, year, and user to speed up the query?

Comment: benchmark it both ways. the overhead of creating/maintaining the columns may very well exceed any benefit from caching the data.

Comment: The PK is a column that doesn't exist in the table. Brilliant!

Comment: Anyway, store dates as dates. And use a range query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better off just restructuring your query's criteria to better take advantage of a possible index on the field:

```
WHERE dateCreated >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00' 
   AND dateCreated < '2016-10-01 00:00:00' 
   AND user = '1234'
```

Comment: Do I need to index dateCreated and user?

Comment: The change I made specifically relies on an index on `dateCreated` to be useful; but having one on `user`, or a combined one on both fields, should be helpful as well. In the bigger picture it really depends on how you expect to be querying the data regularly. For example, an `(dateCreated, user)` index will not be helpful in cases where you are querying based on `user` without `dateCreated`, but will still be helpful if you expect to query often on `dateCreated` without `user`.

Comment: Much better if you reorder that index:  `(user, dateCreated)`.  Put the constant test first, then the range.